# How to make file/result downloadable in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I will request you see this repo: https://github.com/imsikka/ArtGallery

I want to make the result downloadable using a download button, I know how to make a download button but I don't know how it will make the file downloadable, I need to link the button with a specific part code or what?

Well I really don't know how to do it i surfed the net but got nothin really helpful

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. You say you want to make the result downloadable. The result of what, exactly? Do you want to download the HTML contents of the link you mentioned in your question, or do you want to download the zip archive of the repository?

Comment: we had to make a form using PHP which will show the items availablity, sales in a month ofc using Sql you can see the repository. If i want to make those results downloadable how will i do it i can write css code of the download button but how it'll download the results?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand you better now. So, when you click a button, that button should fetch the monthly sales (for example) for you, and then immediately download them? What should the file format be? HTML? PDF? JSON? CSV?

Comment: Any readable file... like these will also generate charts so I would prefer a PDF format. It's a beginner project i just want to make it simple

Comment: If you control the server which is serving the response (the result of your button click), you could use a PDF library, like [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). If you don't, and you can only get the response, then you might want to look into something like [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/) and [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the information you want to download on an uploader site and apply the download link to the button using

Maybe this way you can solve your problem

Info: Conclusion. In HTML, a button link to another page can be by using the  tag,  tag, and the  tag. A link on a button is get by href=”” attribute of  tag. The “type=button” and “onclick=link” attributes are used to create a link on the button.